# android how to handle key events in async task

Tags: android

i am using async task while retrieving data from server,everything is working fine but when i press the back key to navigate to previous activity it throws nullpointer exception

i used `KeyDown()` and `KeyUp()` to handle the key events

Please help me

Comment: Please provide some more information about you problem. Code and log from log cat.

Answer (score 2):

When you press the back button, your activity will finish. You should [cancel](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#cancel%28boolean%29) your AsyncTask, before allowing this to happen. A suitable place to do so is in the OnDestroy method of your activity.

If you don't do that, you will leave a loose thread that will try to access your already destroyed activity, when the background operation finishes. This will most probably cause an exception.

Comment: Though i cancel Async Task the same issue persists

Comment: Post some code and the full stack trace in order to get more help.